React Native Android Build Fails After Cloning Repository, Despite Passing npx react-native doctor
I recently cloned a React Native project repository, and I'm encountering an issue when trying to run the app on an Android device/emulator. After cloning the repository, I ran the necessary installation steps and confirmed that my development environment is set up correctly, but when I attempt to run the app using npm run android, I encounter the following error:
Steps to Reproduce:

Clone the repository: git clone <repo_url>
Navigate to the project directory.
Run npm install to install dependencies.
Run npm run android.

Output when running npm run android:
> coRider@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor.

:ReactNative:Running '[node, D:\Code\INTERNN\CoRider\corider-hybrid-application\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\Code\INTERNN\CoRider\corider-hybrid-application\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 401

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Running '[node, D:\Code\INTERNN\CoRider\corider-hybrid-application\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command failed. FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Script 'D:\Code\INTERNN\CoRider\corider-hybrid-application\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 401 * What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating script. > Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 1s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I ran npx react-native doctor to verify the setup, and the output shows everything is configured correctly:
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ✓ Metro - Required for bundling the JavaScript code

Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Gradlew - Build tool required for Android builds
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Errors:   0
Warnings: 0


I tried running the build with --stacktrace, --info, and --verbose flags, but the issue persists with no additional insight.


Additional Information:

React Native version: 0.74.5 (from package.json)
React version: 18.2.0
Node.js version: 18.x.x
npm version: 10.8.2
OS: Windows 11
Android Studio: Installed and configured correctly, with SDKs and Emulators available.

Project (package.json):
{
  "name": "coRider",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.11.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "appcenter": "5.0.2",
    "appcenter-analytics": "5.0.2",
    "appcenter-crashes": "5.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "coRider": "file:",
    "lucide-react-native": "^0.446.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.76.4",
    "react-native-code-push": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.41.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-otp-inputs": "^7.4.0",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^1.3.7",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.15.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.11.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.34.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.7.1",
    "react-native-ui-datepicker": "^2.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-android": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios": "15.0.1",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.87",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.87",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.87",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.87",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}

What I've Tried:

I confirmed that node and npm are installed and working correctly.
I deleted node_modules and ran npm install again.
I've tried cleaning the Gradle build cache using gradlew clean but still facing the same issue.

What Should I Do Next?
Any help on resolving this issue would be appreciated. Is there any specific configuration or missing setup I need to check? I'm also curious if there are any known issues related to this native_modules.gradle file for this version of React Native.

if you run this command in you terminal node -e "console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);"
what kind of responses do you get ?

I ran the command, and it returned the path:
D:\Code\INTERNN\CoRider\corider-hybrid-application\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js

The file exists, but the issue persists. Any idea what could be causing this?

can you put the content of package.json ? it seems a bug related to one of your dependencies

updated the question body with the package.json file

You shoudn't have react-native-cli in your package.json since the 0.73 version, the React Native CLI is provided with React Native

Check if the "new architecture" is used in this project. If it is, newArchEnabled=true should be set, and the necessary change should be added to the .env file. If it is not set newArchEnabled=false.
stop metro and also delete package-lock.json/yarn.lock when you reinstall node_modules

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
